# How to replace GCP Load Balancer Backend Service Health Check via gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, health-check, gcp-load-balancer

I have some "Classic" HTTP load balancers in my GCP project. Now I need to switch the health check used in one of the backend services.

Here you see in the GUI what I want to do:
[image]

However, as you can see, I got a warning not to change anything via GUI.

So, how do I do this via the gcloud command line tool? Could not find any hint in the docs, unfortunately.

Or can I ignore this warning and just go ahead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning can be ignored. In case if the `health check` is not updated then follow these steps to update the health check through **gcloud commands**.

If you know the name of the **backend service** which you are trying to update the health check, you can use the following command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services update BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME \
    --region=REGION \
    --health-checks=HEALTH_CHECK_NAME \
    --health-checks-region=REGION
```

Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update) for more information about the **backend-service** update command.

In case you don't know the name of the backend-services attached to the load balancer follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#hc-to-bes) to get the list of backend services used by the load balancer. By using the backend service name we can update the health check through gcloud command line tool.